# Azure Container EnumerationResults as HTML

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage

When I go to https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
assume I have my account information included in the url so that it goes to the Enumeration Results of the Container I have chosen.

Is there any ways I can convert the XML output into something in a html table.
I've tried doing this with a simple javascript but this page can not be downloaded as it were and so I can not parse it in this way.
I get the following error when trying to do an

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list", false);
```

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "THE SAME URL AS ABOVE" No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Any solutions, or a way of displaying the Enumeration data like a webserver index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are running into relates to a restriction of web browsers that prevents Javascript requests to resources located in domains other than the one in which the parent page is located. In February we added CORS support to the platform which allows you to define CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policies that can be used to enable such scenarios.

Take a look here for more information [Windows Azure Storage: Introducing CORS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx).

Jason

Comment: So if I setup CORS on the Azure Service, I should be able to get it to work like that. Thanks. I'll have a look at doing that later.

Comment: Great, Managed to get it going :D

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear it!